# Quando devo me preocupar com UX?

Tags: ux

Recentemente tenho visto alguns posts sobre o que é UX (User Experience) e essa parte me parece ser compreensível sobre "o que é?"

No entanto, eu queria saber quando eu devo me preocupar com a UX. Eu sou desenvolvedor web e geralmente faço sistemas de CRUD para empresas. A que ponto a UX pode me ajudar ou dificultar o desenvolvimento?

O que eu quero dizer é: Eu simplesmente faço o que o cliente pede de forma funcional e "bonitinha" ou realmente é bom criar toda a experiencia ?

Comment: "Ser bonitinho" não é prioridade de UX. Melhor é funcionar bem. Claro que o ideal é unir as 2 coisas. Exemplo: o site antigo do registro.br era feio de doer, mas a UX era muito melhor, via-se tudo com facilidade em poucas telas, tinha acesso a tudo em poucos cliques. Hoje é um amontoado de frameworks, desajeitado (mas parece bonitinho, quem usa raramente não percebe tanto como ficou precário)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Sempre", do mais básico ao mais sofisticado software, a não ser que tenha zero interação com usuário mesmo que indiretamente, o que eu nunca vi. Claro que em alguns casos precisa de menos preocupação, na maioria dos casos ninguém morrerá por ter UX ruim.

Não importa se vai dificultar o desenvolvimento, você faz coisas para usuários, se ele não tiver uma boa experiência está fazendo algo ruim. Claro que tem outras variáveis a serem analisadas em cada projeto. E varia de caso para caso. Se todos se preocupassem com UX não teriam softwares tão ruins quanto temos.

UX é muito importante! Ponto.

- Funcionar é UX.
- Dar o resultado certo, esperado, sempre, na hora certa, do jeito certo é UX.
- Usar termos certos para o público é UX.
- Não ser excessivo é UX.
- Ser fácil de usar e de aprender (intuitivo para seu público) é UX.
- Permitir agilidade e fácil correção de equívocos é UX.
- Orientar o usuário com dificuldade de forma efetiva é UX. Monitorar pode ser UX.
- Rodar na plataforma fácil com a interface certa é UX.
- Ser bonito e agradável é UX.
- Ser rápido é UX.
- Não dar erro é UX.
- Não enganar o usuário é UX.
- E a lista pode continuar...

UX não é só visual, que fique claro, muitas pessoas confundem UX com UI. A primeira é a experiência como um todo, a segunda é a interação com o usuário de forma direta, e até esta parte não é só visual. UX é fazer o usuário sentir-se bem usando seu software. Não é ele que é burro por não usar o seu software, é você que não conseguiu atingir seu objetivo de UX.

Tem coisas que são naturais, não é questão de decidir se fará ou não. Tem aspectos que podem complicar o software por não ter boa UX. Muitos casos causará *recall*, está preparado para isso? Está no contrato? Tem orçamento para isso?

O orçamento permite lidar bem com todos os aspectos de UX? De um jeito formal ou só intuitivo do que deve fazer? Nunca dá para analisar sem olhar tudo isto.

Se pode fazer o melhor porque faria menos que isso?

[image: UX Ruim - Caminho usado pelas pessoas diferente do projetado]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

Concordo com a resposta acima! "Sempre".

Complementando, o UX faz diferença diretamenta na aquisição e retenção de seus usuários. E lembre que as experiencias vão mudando ao longo dos anos. O que tinhamos como ótima experiência a 10 ou 5 anos atrás mudou e vem mudando.

Cada experiência que o usuário tem, seja boa ou ruim, ele leva para outro usuário e isso gera uma cadência de informações que devem e precisam ser analisadas, coletadas e trabalhadas. É assim que o bom UX funciona, ele permite que cada percepção seja melhor do que você já aplica, trazendo uma perspectiva diferente do que o seu usuário já está familiarizado.

Fazer UX não é simples, mas através de uma boa análise de comportamento pode-se criar uma proposta de valor, com uma projeção clara do que se deve fazer e provocando sensações através das experiências.

Se puder ler um pouco sobre os trabalhos e literaturas dos três nomes abaixo vais dar um bom start para entender o porque é tão importante e também ver casos de sucesso para ampliar sua mente abrangendo sua visão sobre o negócio

1. Jakob Nielsen
2. Steve Jobs
3. Elon Musk

UX é um grande passo para o sucesso de uma aplicação.
Vou deixar um link de UX que gosto muito [aqui](https://oito.digital/beneficios-de-ux-design-negocio-digital/). Abraços e parabéns pelo questionamento.